# Twilio sudo: pon: command not found

Tags: twilio

I'm setting twilio modem for raspberry pi 3
Following instructions from twilio at 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/wireless/connect-using-raspberry-pi-and-cellular-usb-modem#connect-to-the-cellular-network
The modem (Huwaei) is recognized, installation completed.
When trying to turn on through:

sudo pon twilio

Pi print

sudo: pon: command not found

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I can find, `pon` is a tool for PPP connections. Looking through [the instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/wireless/connect-using-raspberry-pi-and-cellular-usb-modem#connect-to-the-cellular-network) up to that point, this one stands out:

```
sudo apt-get install ppp usb-modeswitch
```

Can you ensure that `ppp` successfully installs as part of that process and then try running the `sudo pon twilio` command again.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem was that usb modem was in storage mode and not modem mode.